# Java program runtime error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
public class BooksTestDrive {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Books [] myBooks = new Books[3];
  int x=0;
  myBooks[0].title = "The Grapes of Jave";
  myBooks[1].title = "The Java Gatsby";
  myBooks[2].title = "The Java Cookbook";
  myBooks[0].author = "bob";
  myBooks[1].author = "sue";
  myBooks[2].author = "ian";

 while (x < 3) {
  System.out.print(myBooks[x].title);
  System.out.print("by");
  System.out.println(myBooks[x].author);
  x = x+1;
  }
 }
}
```

This code compiles but while runtime, its giving nullpointer exception.

Comment: Always indicate what line the exception was thrown in!  For more complex problems include the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Exactly where does the exception is thrown ?

Answer (score 5):

Your allocation of MyBooks[3] only assigns the *array*  You still need to assign a "new MyBook()" to each entry in your array.

Answer (score 2):

look at your line:

```
Books [] myBooks = new Books[3];
```

you create an array, although every element in the array is a null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Saw it, you need to initializate each one of the elments of your array, try it with in an `for` or a `while`

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
public class BooksTestDrive {
public static void main(String[] args) { 
      Books [] myBooks = new Books[3];
      // init loop
      for (int i=0;i<myBooks.length;i++) {
         myBooks[i] = new Books();
      }

      myBooks[0].title = "The Grapes of Jave";
      myBooks[1].title = "The Java Gatsby";
      myBooks[2].title = "The Java Cookbook";
      myBooks[0].author = "bob";
      myBooks[1].author = "sue";
      myBooks[2].author = "ian";

      for (Books book : myBooks) {
          System.out.printf("%s by %s\n",book.title,book.author);
      }
     }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the books to the arrays. This should work:

```
class BooksTestDrive {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Books [] myBooks = new Books[3];
        int x = 0;
        // THIS IS WHAT WAS MISSING.
        myBooks[0] = new Books();
        myBooks[1] = new Books();
        myBooks[2] = new Books();

        myBooks[0].title = "The Grapes of Java";
        myBooks[1].title = "The Java Gatsby";
        myBooks[2].title = "The Java Cookbook";
        myBooks[0].author = "bob";
        myBooks[1].author = "sue";
        myBooks[2].author = "ian";

        while (x < 3) {
            System.out.print(myBooks[x].title);
            System.out.print(" by ");
            System.out.println(myBooks[x].author) ;
            x = x + 1;
        }
    }
}
```